# setOnItemClickListener doesn't work when setOnLongClickListener is being used - Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

As the subject suggests, setOnItemClickListener doesn't work when setOnLongClickListener is being used, the layout I'm using in the base adapter is below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">


    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contacts_grid_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Mobile number"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="9dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and I'm using this,

```
image.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());
                String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

                ClipData dragData = new ClipData("test", mimeTypes, item);

                MyDragShadowBuilder myShadow = new MyDragShadowBuilder(holder.image);
                if (groups.size() > holder.position) {
                    v.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);

        return true;
            }
        });
```

and this,

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                 Log.i(TAG, "clicked");

            }
        });
```

Now when I tap on the image the item click doesn't work, but when i click on the text views it works, what am i doing wrong?

Also note that when I remove the image.setOnLongClickListener() the whole gridview item becomes clickable again.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Try returning `false` in `OnLongClickListener#onLongClick()`

Comment: I just tried that, it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This should be the expected behaviour for GridView, because the child view is clickable, even though it is only handling the OnLongClick only.

As a workaround, you can

1. `setOnClickListener` for ImageView to perform the same action as you would in `setOnItemClickListener`
2. consider using `setOnItemLongClickListener`, but this would affect the whole RelativeLayout
3. use `onTouchListener`, but this would requires more works